# implementation of command line arg passing in python, doesn't work

Tags: python

I'm very new to python. I wish I could implement the command-line arg passing in python as my first python script. I have written this code:

```
def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hb:b:f", ["help", "bucket=", "folder"])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    s3 = get_files()
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-b", "--bucket"):
            s3.bucketname = arg
        elif opt in ("-f", "--folder"):
            s3.foldername = arg
            print("Came here" + s3.foldername)
    s3.download_files()
```

In the `-f` argument from command is where I'm facing the problem. For debugging I used the `print` statement. I pass the arguments like this:

```
./hello -b something -f /path
```

but sadly it prints out:

```
Came here
```

But the `foldername` attribute is not getting assigned any value. Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) ([tutorial](http://docs.python.org/howto/argparse.html)) for command line arguments parsing which will make your task much easier.

Comment: But why doesn't this work! It is catching my `-f` argument in the `elif` statement. But nothing getting assigned to my `foldername`

Comment: The indentation in the example you've posted is incorrect. You need to fix that. Remember that in Python indentation is part of the language syntax.

Comment: Shouldn't the short option string be `"hb:f:"`?  With the option string you've specified, `-f` isn't supposed to have an "argument".

Comment: @jszakmeister: Yes your correct! That fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argparse really is a much simpler way of solving problems like this

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--bucket', dest='bucketname', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--folder', dest='folder', action='store')
    args = parser.parse_args('-b foo'.split())
    print args
    args = parser.parse_args('-b foo -f /foo'.split())
    print args
```

Gives:

```
> Namespace(bucketname='foo', folder=None)
> Namespace(bucketname='foo', folder='/foo')
```

Which means you could rewrite your function as:

```
import sys
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--bucket', dest='bucketname', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--folder', dest='folder', action='store')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    s3 = get_files()
    s3.foldername = args.folder
    s3.download_files()
```

Without any further work, the output of `script.py --help` is:

```
usage: script.py [-h] [-b BUCKETNAME] [-f FOLDER]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -b BUCKETNAME, --bucket BUCKETNAME
  -f FOLDER, --folder FOLDE
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case how would I find the unexpected arguments? And render the users the help message?

Comment: Thanks just noticed that it creates the help message automatically! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten the equal sign after "folder", it should be `getopt.getopt(argv, "hbf:", ["help", "bucket=", "folder="])`, right?

Your indentation is incorrect, and should cause a syntax error. It should be:

```
elif opt in ("-f", "--folder"):
    s3.foldername = arg
```

As others have pointed out, [argparse](http://docs.python.org/howto/argparse.html) is nice.